# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' in class

Tags: model-view-controller

I m trying to run below code and getting error can not implicitly convert string to int CS0029
on code         new Customer { Name ="Cust one"} ,
new Customer { Name = "Customer2" }

find below full code

```
public ActionResult Random() // Random is action result or object name to be made any action
        {
           var customers  = new List<Customer>
            {
                new Customer { Name ="Cust one"} ,
                new Customer { Name = "Customer2" }
            };
            var viewModel = new RandomMovieViewModel
            {
                Movie = movie,
                Customers = customers
            };
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We don't know what `Customer` or `RandomMovieViewModel` look like.

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: Looks like C# to me.

Comment: @Syed - you need to tag your questions properly.  This is nothing to do with `[model-view-controller]`.